# Approximating time and position of an object along a BezierCurve in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have an object that I'm moving a long a Bezier curve by sampling a few points along the curve and then just using Unity's MoveTowards to move the object to each point at a constant speed.

Before I do this though, I want to approximate the time that the object will reach the each of the points which I am currently doing by calculating the distance between the points and then just dividing that by the speed of the car.

The values I get are off usually off by one or two decimal places and what I've noticed is that the time values change. Does Unity do some things under the hood that I should take into account and is it possible to get more accurate results, at least to 1 decimal point?

EDIT: Here's some of the code so you can see what I'm trying to do:

This is the internal simulation

```
    float initialTime = Time.time;
    Debug.Log("Initial time simulation: " + initialTime);
    float distance = 0;
    Vector3 curr = transform.position;
    Vector3 next;

    for (int s = 1; s < steps+1; ++s)
    {
        float segment = (1.0f - (s/ (float)steps)); 
        next = curve.GetPointAt(segment);
        next.y = curr.y; //Only using x and z of bezier curves
        distance += (next - curr).magnitude;
        curr = next;

        float elapsedTime = distance / speed;
        output[s - 1] = new KeyValuePair<float, Vector3>(initialTime+elapsedTime, point);
    }
```

This is what actually gets simulated

```
    int counter = 1;
    Debug.Log("Initial Time Actual: " + Time.time);
    Vector3 toPoint = curve.GetPointAt((float)(steps - counter) / (steps));
    toPoint.y = transform.position.y;
    transform.LookAt(toPoint);
    while (counter <= steps)
    {

        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, toPoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.LookAt(newPos);
        transform.position = newPos; 

        if (transform.position == toPoint)
        {
            Debug.Log("CurrTime: " + Time.time + " " + transform.position);
            ++counter;
            toPoint = curve.GetPointAt((float)(steps - counter) / (steps));
            toPoint.y = transform.position.y;
            transform.LookAt(toPoint);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide more details I can only guess you are not taking `Time.deltaTime` into account when calculating the distance you move the car on each frame.

See, `Update()` function executes on every frame, but the time between frames is not necesarily uniform. `Time.deltaTime` gives you the time passed between the last frame and the current one.

You have to do something like this, as suggested in the Unity [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html):

```
private Vector3[] bezierTargets;
private float speed;
private int currentTarget;
// ...
void Update() {
    // ...
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, bezierTargets[currentTarget].position, step);
}
```